# Handling multiple HTTP connections

Tags: java, multithreading, http

I finished coding a java application that uses 25 different threads, each thread is an infinite loop where an http request is sent and the json object(small one) that is returned is processed. It is crucial that the time between two requests sent by a specific thread is less than 500ms. However, I did some benchmark on my program and that time is well over 1000ms. SO my question is: Is there a better way to handle multiple connections other than creating multiple threads ? 
I am in desperate need for help so I'm thankful for any advice you may have !

PS: I have a decent internet connection ( my ping to the destination server of the requests is about 120ms).

Comment: You can always play with the number (25) and it can be higher or lesser.  It is better to use the HTTP Connection Pooling as a suggestion.  There are so many frameworks that are available and I not sure, why you would create these by yourself?   You can think of Jetty as an option here as well.

Comment: do you know where the current bottleneck in your code is?  my guess is "no".  in which case, you should _first_ run your code in a profiler to determine the bottleneck.  _then_ you should figure out how to remove it.

Comment: I appreciated the help ;) I will look into profiling the app thanks .

Comment: Are you using URLConnection or apache's HttpClient?

Comment: Maybe if you describe _WHY_ your program has these requirements we can suggest alternative implementation approaches.

Comment: I'm using URLConnection. There is no alternative to using 25 threads as the server from which I get the json file has 25 streams.

Comment: Is it possible that the problem lies with the server rather than your program? If I am reading this right, your program wants to initiate a new request every 0.5 sec on each connection - but what if the server takes more than 0.5 secs to respond? Why does your program **have** to use all 25 streams to the server?

Comment: Also, does each of your threads hold the connection open between multiple requests, or is the server closing it after each one?

Comment: I'm getting a little tired of the "*help my code runs slow but I'm going to not even talk about what I'm trying to do and blame it on something that's probably wrong*" questions.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking at [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/):

Specifically, you'll be interested in constructing a client that has a pooling connection manager. You can then leverage the same client.

```
PoolingClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingClientConnectionManager();
connectionManager.setMaxTotal(number);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager);
```

Here's a specific example that handles your use-case:

- [PoolingConnectionManager example](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java)